# Adding required props to child react elements with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to define a parent element where I need to pass down some react elements as props. I want to add some requirements on the props to the child components but I can't get my typescript working exactly as intended. Here is a minimal example

```js
import * as React from "react";

function JSXElementChild() {
  return <div>Child One</div>;
}

const ReactFCChild: React.FC<{ label: string }> = ({ label }) => {
  return <div>{label}</div>;
};

function Parent({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactElement<{ label: string }>[];
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children.map((child) => (
        <div key={child.props.label}>{child}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <Parent children={[<JSXElementChild />, <ReactFCChild />]} />;
}
```

`Parent` component requires `children` as props and these children requires a `label: string` as props. Now the above does correct mark a typescript issue with `ReactFCChild`; `Property 'label' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ label: string; }'.ts(2741)`. However `JSXElementChild` does not yield any issues. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Fully updated answer.
Please keep in mind, you should explicitly type `React.FC`, and you should not use `JSX` for root component

```js
import * as React from "react";


const JSXElementChild: React.FC = () => {
    return <div>Child One</div>;
}

const ReactFCChild: React.FC<{ label: string }> = ({ label }) => {
    return <div>{label}</div>;
};

function Parent({
    children
}: {
    children: React.ReactElement<{ label: string }>[];
}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {children.map((child) => (
                <div key={child.props.label}>{child}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return React.createElement(Parent, {
        children: [
            React.createElement(JSXElementChild, null), //  error
            React.createElement(ReactFCChild, { label: 'd' }) // no error
        ]
    });
}

function App2() {
    return React.createElement(Parent, {
        children: [
            /**
             * still error, because JSXElementChild don't expect {label: string}
             * If you add typings for JSXElementChild, error will disappear
             */
            React.createElement(JSXElementChild, { label: 'd' }), //error
            React.createElement(ReactFCChild, { label: 'd' }) // no error
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I realize that. That was on purpose - I'd expect typescript to automatically raise an issue when those props are not defined

Comment: Does my solution helped?

Comment: No - I want typescript to raise an issue on the JSXElementChild as I implemented it. Your "solution" is just a replica of ReactFCChild unfortunately.

Comment: You can try to type it with propTypes. Here https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/issues/102#issuecomment-481270592

Comment: This issue can be also useful https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Comment: @mr.bjerre please take a look on updated answer